# Split S3 files into multiple output files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mapreduce

I am uploading my database results as text file to S3 cluster. Now I need to split this file into multiple files in S3 based on column names combination. After that the individual files will be given to a service which will do some preprocessing on this individual files in parallel. After which they will be combined together as a single file and stored back to s3.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769576/efficiently-split-files-in-s3